# Selenium testing for EPIC IE-based application

Tags: selenium, epic

I want to use Selenium to test EPIC application.
EPIC only runs on Internet Explorer, and in our environment, we launch EPIC thru Citrix.

Is it possible to use any tools in the Selenium suite to launch EPIC thru Citrix, record the test and then rerun the test?

If yes, please give me some leads on how to do this kind of test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get to the CITRIX, but I can't login to the EPIC as it is a JAVA application.

Comment: If you need to interact with Java applets (I have no idea what Citrix or Epic is), [LiveConnect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect) can help you with that. There's no working Selenium helper to make it easy, though.